# Error 404 on edit rows - Backpack crud- Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

I'm actually inserting data without problems on my DB...but when I try to edit one row and save the changes... it throws me this error...

"No query results for model [model's name]"

I already try to fix that with => protected $primaryKey = 'id'; On my model.

But still getting the same error ....any help ?

The specific error route looks like 
 "admin/titulares/2"

and before I press the save button like "admin/titulares/2/edit"

[image: Editing a row]

My routes

```
Route::group([
'middleware' => ['prefix'     => config('backpack.base.route_prefix', 'admin'),
                'web', config('backpack.base.middleware_key', 'admin')],
                'namespace'  => 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin',
                ], function () { // custom admin routes
                Route::get('dashboard', 'dashboardController@dashboard');

                #CRUD::resource('equipos', 'EquiposCrudController');
                #CRUD::resource('regiones', 'RegionesCrudController');
                CRUD::resource('parametros', 'ParametrosCrudController');
                CRUD::resource('estaciones', 'EstacionesCrudController');
                #CRUD::resource('redes', 'RedesCrudController');
                #CRUD::resource('huso', 'HusoCrudController');
                CRUD::resource('titulares', 'TitularesCrudController');
                CRUD::resource('operadores', 'OperadoresCrudController');
               });
```

UPDATE:

This is my edit form action (it uses https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/html)

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => $crud->route.'/'.$entry->getKey(), 'method' => 'put', 'files'=>$crud->hasUploadFields('update', $entry->getKey()))) !!}
```

Comment: Sharing a link to **your** local machine isn't going to help! Can you provide any relevant code - like your controller for this?

Comment: Done , I have included routes and edit form action @WildBeard

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure using right method for update, You should use put for update data, for example,

`Route::put('example/{id}', 'ExampleController@update')`

I hope this will help

Comment: I have updated my question with the routes I have...The module's name is Titulares..it is not enough to have that crud route to add ,edit and delete ? :/

Comment: yesi it is enough, Are you sure using right `action` and `route` on blade for update data?

Comment: I have update the question again...thank you for your time